# Ошибка php Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query in C:\Users\mahmu\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\Venitore.rp\rcabin.php on line 40

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Моя задача из БД получить логин и вывести его на экран, но ничего не получается выходит лишь только ошибка Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query in C:\Users\mahmu\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\Venitore.rp\rcabin.php on line 40

Вот строка на которую ругается php

```
<p class="text">Ник: <?php $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login`"; $result = mysqli_query($connect, $result); $login = $_POST['login']; echo($login);?></p>
```

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($connect, $result);`? Ты понимаешь что тут написано?

Comment: Ответ еще нужен - или  u_mulder донес мысль?

Comment: А, ой, я код писал ночью и видимо не заметил, но я изменил эту часть кода на: $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); но теперь вместо ошибки ничего не происходит. Есть варианты решение проблемы?